# How to install Visual Studio 12 BuildTools in Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2012, docker-for-windows

I'm new to Docker and I'm preparing myself for possible migration of my project that is currently build using Visual Studio 2012 (update 4) to run in docker container. I've installed the Docker in Windows Server 2019 running inside HyperV VM on my machine. I came across [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-dockerfiles/blob/master/native-desktop/Dockerfile) for setting up VS Build tool.

```
# escape=`

# Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE.txt in the project root for license information.

ARG FROM_IMAGE=microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5-sdk-windowsservercore-1709
FROM ${FROM_IMAGE}

# Reset the shell.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Set up environment to collect install errors.
COPY Install.cmd C:\TEMP\
ADD https://aka.ms/vscollect.exe C:\TEMP\collect.exe

# Install Node.js LTS
ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-x64.msi C:\TEMP\node-install.msi
RUN start /wait msiexec.exe /i C:\TEMP\node-install.msi /l*vx "%TEMP%\MSI-node-install.log" /qn ADDLOCAL=ALL

# Download channel for fixed install.
ARG CHANNEL_URL=https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel
ADD ${CHANNEL_URL} C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman

# Download and install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 for native desktop workload.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
RUN C:\TEMP\Install.cmd C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --channelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --installChannelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended`
    --installPath C:\BuildTools

# Use developer command prompt and start PowerShell if no other command specified.
ENTRYPOINT C:\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat &&
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Initially I was getting error saying my OS version doesn't match `the container operating system does not match the host operating system`, so I changed below line :

`ARG FROM_IMAGE=microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5-sdk-windowsservercore-1709`

To below:

`ARG FROM_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

Then it seems the BuildTool was able to install. Now I want to modify the docker file to create the BuildTool for VS2012. So I changed below line:

```
# Download channel for fixed install.
ARG CHANNEL_URL=https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/channel
ADD ${CHANNEL_URL} C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman

# Download and install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 for native desktop workload.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
RUN C:\TEMP\Install.cmd C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --channelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --installChannelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended`
    --installPath C:\BuildTools
```

To below (Replace version 15 with 11)

```
# Download channel for fixed install.
ARG CHANNEL_URL=https://aka.ms/vs/11/release/channel
ADD ${CHANNEL_URL} C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman

# Download and install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2012 for native desktop workload.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/11/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
RUN C:\TEMP\Install.cmd C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --channelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --installChannelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended`
    --installPath C:\BuildTools
```

After above changes, when I run again `docker build -t buildtools2012native:latest -m 2GB .` , I got below error:

```
Step 11/13 : RUN C:\TEMP\Install.cmd C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache     --channelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman     --installChannelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman     --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended    --installPath C:\BuildTools
 ---> Running in 0bb58dcd923f
This version of C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio/.NET Log Collection Tool version 16.0.28407.115
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
```

Please help me understand how to fix this problem?
Additionally, Can I build my Applications(Windows Services and a GUI application) and associated DLLs on different machine and run inside docker?